# How can a componet auto update content?

Tags: java, swing

I am a newbie in Swing library. I am trying to make an desktop application like [this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2ZCB0.png).

This JFileChooser object is for choosing the destination directory to show the tree on right Pane.

But when I choose a directory, tree in the right Pane is not changed to view a new tree of the new destination direction.

What I can do next for it ?  Thanks for your help 
Here is my code :

```
public class DesktopUI {

    private Path pathDirectChoose ;
    private final File root = new File("/");
    private File des;

    public DesktopUI(){
        initUI();
    }
    public void setPathDirectChoose(Path pathDirectChoose){
        this.pathDirectChoose = pathDirectChoose;
    }
    public void setDes(String des){
        this.des = new File(des);
    }

    private void initUI(){
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("TestProject");
        //make TopMenuBar
        JMenuBar menuBar = new JMenuBar();
        JMenu optionMenu = new JMenu("Option");
        JMenuItem chooseSecretFolder = new JMenuItem("Choose Secret Folder");
        JMenuItem exitItem = new JMenuItem("Exit");
        JMenu helpMenu = new JMenu("Help");
        JMenuItem helpItem = new JMenuItem("?Help");
        JMenuItem aboutItem = new JMenuItem("About");

        // config chooseSecretFolder
        chooseSecretFolder.setToolTipText("Choose destinaion folder to encrypt");
        chooseSecretFolder.setAccelerator(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_S, InputEvent.CTRL_MASK));
        exitItem.setAccelerator(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_E,InputEvent.CTRL_MASK));
        helpItem.setAccelerator(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_H,InputEvent.CTRL_MASK));
        chooseSecretFolder.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                File selectedDirect = null;
                JFileChooser fileChooser = new JFileChooser();
                fileChooser.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.DIRECTORIES_ONLY);
                fileChooser.setCurrentDirectory(new File(System.getProperty("user.home")));
                int result = fileChooser.showOpenDialog(fileChooser);
                selectedDirect = fileChooser.getSelectedFile();
                setPathDirectChoose(selectedDirect.toPath());
                setDes(String.valueOf(pathDirectChoose));
                System.out.println(String.valueOf(pathDirectChoose));

            }
        });

        //add ActionListener for exit Item
        exitItem.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                System.exit(0);
            }
        });

        optionMenu.add(chooseSecretFolder);
        optionMenu.add(exitItem);
        helpMenu.add(helpItem);
        helpMenu.add(aboutItem);
        menuBar.add(optionMenu);
        menuBar.add(helpMenu);
        frame.setJMenuBar(menuBar);

        //make JTextField to show PathFile choosed and view Tree
        JTextField pathFileJText = new JTextField();
        JTree leftTree = new JTree(new FileTreeModel(root));
        JTree rightTree = new JTree(new FileTreeModel(des));
        JSplitPane splitPane = new JSplitPane(JSplitPane.HORIZONTAL_SPLIT);
        JScrollPane leftPane = new JScrollPane(leftTree);
        JScrollPane rightPane = new JScrollPane(rightTree);
        //add TreeSelectionListener for tree system
        leftTree.addTreeSelectionListener(new TreeSelectionListener() {
            @Override
            public void valueChanged(TreeSelectionEvent e) {
                Object object = e.getPath().getLastPathComponent();
                System.out.println(object);
                pathFileJText.setText(object.toString());
                // make a popupMenu when file be choosed
                JPopupMenu popupMenu = new JPopupMenu();
                JMenuItem encryptFile = new JMenuItem("Encrypt File");
                JMenuItem decryptFile = new JMenuItem("Decrypt File");
                popupMenu.add(encryptFile);
                popupMenu.add(decryptFile);

                leftTree.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
                    @Override
                    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
                        super.mouseReleased(e);
                        if (e.getButton() == MouseEvent.BUTTON3){
                            popupMenu.show(e.getComponent(),e.getX(),e.getY());
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        });

        //show all componets
        splitPane.setLeftComponent(leftPane);
        splitPane.setRightComponent(rightPane);
        frame.add(pathFileJText,BorderLayout.NORTH);
        frame.add(splitPane,BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(500,500);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                DesktopUI desktopUI = new DesktopUI();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to update your tree with a new model, when you set new directory. Something like `rightTree.setModel(new FileTreeModel(des));` in your `setDes` method. To do it, you need to declare your `rightTree` variable as object property.

Comment: how can i declare my rightTree var as object property .  and how about using PropertyChangeListener?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've corrected your example, but I'm not sure whether it works because you haven't provided [SSCCE](http://sscce.org)

```
public class DesktopUI {

    private Path pathDirectChoose ;
    private final File root = new File("/");
    private File des;
    private JTree rightTree; // declare as object property

    public DesktopUI(){
        initUI();
    }
    public void setPathDirectChoose(Path pathDirectChoose){
        this.pathDirectChoose = pathDirectChoose;
    }
    public void setDes(String des){
        this.des = new File(des);
        rightTree.setModel(new FileTreeModel(des));
    }

    private void initUI(){
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("TestProject");
        //make TopMenuBar
        JMenuBar menuBar = new JMenuBar();
        JMenu optionMenu = new JMenu("Option");
        JMenuItem chooseSecretFolder = new JMenuItem("Choose Secret Folder");
        JMenuItem exitItem = new JMenuItem("Exit");
        JMenu helpMenu = new JMenu("Help");
        JMenuItem helpItem = new JMenuItem("?Help");
        JMenuItem aboutItem = new JMenuItem("About");

        // config chooseSecretFolder
        chooseSecretFolder.setToolTipText("Choose destinaion folder to encrypt");
        chooseSecretFolder.setAccelerator(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_S, InputEvent.CTRL_MASK));
        exitItem.setAccelerator(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_E,InputEvent.CTRL_MASK));
        helpItem.setAccelerator(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_H,InputEvent.CTRL_MASK));
        chooseSecretFolder.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                File selectedDirect = null;
                JFileChooser fileChooser = new JFileChooser();
                fileChooser.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.DIRECTORIES_ONLY);
                fileChooser.setCurrentDirectory(new File(System.getProperty("user.home")));
                int result = fileChooser.showOpenDialog(fileChooser);
                selectedDirect = fileChooser.getSelectedFile();
                setPathDirectChoose(selectedDirect.toPath());
                setDes(String.valueOf(pathDirectChoose));
                System.out.println(String.valueOf(pathDirectChoose));

            }
        });

        //add ActionListener for exit Item
        exitItem.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                System.exit(0);
            }
        });


        optionMenu.add(chooseSecretFolder);
        optionMenu.add(exitItem);
        helpMenu.add(helpItem);
        helpMenu.add(aboutItem);
        menuBar.add(optionMenu);
        menuBar.add(helpMenu);
        frame.setJMenuBar(menuBar);

        //make JTextField to show PathFile choosed and view Tree
        JTextField pathFileJText = new JTextField();
        JTree leftTree = new JTree(new FileTreeModel(root));
        rightTree = new JTree(new FileTreeModel(des)); // no type declaration here
        JSplitPane splitPane = new JSplitPane(JSplitPane.HORIZONTAL_SPLIT);
        JScrollPane leftPane = new JScrollPane(leftTree);
        JScrollPane rightPane = new JScrollPane(rightTree);
        //add TreeSelectionListener for tree system
        leftTree.addTreeSelectionListener(new TreeSelectionListener() {
            @Override
            public void valueChanged(TreeSelectionEvent e) {
                Object object = e.getPath().getLastPathComponent();
                System.out.println(object);
                pathFileJText.setText(object.toString());
                // make a popupMenu when file be choosed
                JPopupMenu popupMenu = new JPopupMenu();
                JMenuItem encryptFile = new JMenuItem("Encrypt File");
                JMenuItem decryptFile = new JMenuItem("Decrypt File");
                popupMenu.add(encryptFile);
                popupMenu.add(decryptFile);

                leftTree.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
                    @Override
                    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
                        super.mouseReleased(e);
                        if (e.getButton() == MouseEvent.BUTTON3){
                            popupMenu.show(e.getComponent(),e.getX(),e.getY());

                        }
                    }
                });
            }

        });

        //show all componets
        splitPane.setLeftComponent(leftPane);
        splitPane.setRightComponent(rightPane);
        frame.add(pathFileJText,BorderLayout.NORTH);
        frame.add(splitPane,BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(500,500);
        frame.setVisible(true);

    }




    public static void main(String[] args){
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                DesktopUI desktopUI = new DesktopUI();
            }
        });

    }
}
```

Comment: It worked. setModel() in setDes() refesh FileTreeModell when i choose a new des var.Thank you very much . Now I can do next work to complete my application   @Sergiy Meddvynskyy

Comment: @thaibuixuan in this case please mark my answer as helpful (check-mark left to answer). You'll get 2 points of reputation.

Comment: Hello . Now i try to replace rightTree by a JList But I dont know to make a FileListMode to update list when i choose a new Directory in JFileChooser . Can you help me ! @Sergiy Medvynskyy

Comment: @thaibuixuan please ask a new question and post your new code in form of [mcve] there.